# Nignx Redirect rule to a different url based on a query

Tags: nginx, rewrite, ubuntu-12.04, proxypass

We have a wordpress installation and need to redirect lost password link to another different url for this we trying to setup a redirect rule but this is not working. Can anyone please help us.

```
location / {
proxy_pass      http://localhost;
     }

location wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
rewrite     ^(.*)  http://recover.geo.com $1 permanent;
}
```

But login url too (wp-login.php?action=login) is redirecting to recover.geo.com

We need to redirect only the url **wp-login.php?action=lostpassword** to other and all other url including **wp-login.php?action=login** need to proxypass

Can anyone please help us with the correct configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `location` for this at all. It doesn't match on query string arguments.

Instead, just check the argument and request URI directly. For example:

```
location / {
    if ($arg_action = "lostpassword") {
        rewrite /wp-login.php http://recover.geo.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword permanent;
    }

    # everything else...
}
```

Comment: I would use `location /wp-login.php` and then the if statement inside, with `rewrite ^ http://recover`. This way nginx won't do the `if` for every request coming to the site.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes, but then you have to repeat all the directives to pass non-matching requests onward to PHP, which makes it less clean.

Comment: True, very good point.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Its working perfectly.....Again Thanks All..